# PHP show full blank text when sentence has accent mark

Tags: php, json, database, mysqli, encoding

the web shows full blank text when the sentence has a special character (í,ú,ó,é,á)in the database column.

The database its in utf8_general_ci and all the columns.

**index.php**

```
    <?php

    require_once 'db.php';

    $query = "SELECT * FROM Frases ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1";

    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        print(json_encode($row['frase']));
    };

?>
```

**db.php**

```
<?php

    // Create connection
    $con=mysqli_connect("host","user","pass","database");

    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_error()){
        echo "Faild to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }


?>
```

I have tried in different rows of the database to take out and place different special characters, and whenever they are present, and I reload the page, these rows appear empty.

**Thank you.**

When i try `mysqli_set_charset($link, 'utf8');` in the index.php before the SELECT dosent do anything.

And `$mysqli->set_charset('utf8');` it crashes the page.

**UPDATE:**
**index.php**

```
<?php

    require_once 'db.php';
    mysqli_set_charset($con,'utf8');
    $query = "SELECT * FROM Frases ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1";

    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        print(json_encode($row['frase']));
    };

?>
```

db.php had no change

**UPDATE 2**
Solution:
index.php

```
<?php

    require_once 'db.php';

    mysqli_set_charset($con,'utf8mb4');

    $query = "SELECT * FROM Frases ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1";

    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        print($row['frase']);
    };

?>
```

Comment: Can you define "special characters"?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner yes, i refer to  (í,ú,ó,é,á)

Comment: Ok. Well, seeing the edit. If it crashes the page, see what logs say and/or enabling and using PHP's error reporting, set to catch and display.

Comment: Looking at your edit again. You have `$mysqli` and `$link`. Both are wrong. You're using `$con` as the connection.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner yep, im sorry with ```$con``` it work, but its show me the unicode character , using ```mysqli_set_charset($con, 'utf8');```

Comment: Can you update your question with the actual code? That way we'll know or hope to see if there's something you might have missed or didn't use properly.

Comment: Another thing. You need to have followed everything in the duplicates to the letter that @mario closed it with. By "everything", we/I mean *everything*. For example; which encoding was used to save the files as. There's more info on this in the duplicate(s).

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner i update the question now, i think i do everything like the duplicates, thats why i still here, i dont know why dosent work

Comment: What happens if you remove the `json_encode()` function?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner  its work perfectly, Thank you very much, so what its this happend?

Comment: You're welcome. It's hard for me to find out why it did that. Maybe it's because you're trying to encode something that isn't JSON or you need to pass a constant's flag, per the manual https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php - I'd have to read more on it, but maybe the reason lies in there. Maybe @mario could shed some light on this or someone else. I am not familiar with JSON. Cheers

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Thank you very much.

Comment: Welcome, anytime :D